# Firewall options when hosting dedicated servers

Tags: firewall, haproxy

I am sort of spoiled with EC2 and its ease of use when it comes to firewall/security group settings.

Now if I go with dedicated servers, say I have a setup like:

- haproxy exposed to the public
- haproxy will proxy requests to web servers (windows IIS for example)
- the web servers will connect to a db server (which is private, hidden from the public).

What options do I have?

I just want to expose haproxy to the public, which will proxy requests to web servers.

HAProxy will be running on Ubuntu.

Would I ask the hosting company to setup the other servers on a private network or?

I really need some guidance here :)

Comment: dedicated _virtual_ servers or physical (i.e. bring-your-own-servers colo facility)?

Comment: renting servers at softlayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going the "managed services" option, you should discuss your *business level* requirements with your hosting company.  If you can clearly describe what you need, they should be able to provide you with the right solution.  Conversely, if you go in waving a detailed description of a setup that someone gave you here, the hosting company might have to say "I'm sorry, we don't support that", which doesn't do anyone any good.

The description you've given in this question should suffice for a reasonably clued hosting company.  They can be tricky to find, though...

If, on the other hand, you're planning on managing everything yourself, you don't really have to ask the hosting company for anything -- they give you a network connection, you hook up everything yourself and configure it to your needs.

Comment: Well I want to do it myself, and learn what my options are etc. hence the question.  I have allot to learn I understand, just want to know my options.

Comment: @codecompleting: I think (one of) womble's points was that you may not have the option to do it all yourself, especially if they don't allow you to alter the standard network and/or rack configuration.

Comment: ah I see, alright makes sense.

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you want to do it all yourself, you don't have to ask the hosting company anything -- they give you a network port and you install and configure your chosen equipment.